# What does digit badge mean at extension icon at VS Code extensions list?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently noticed that over the Python extension icon a new badge with digit appeared, as well as at Remote - SSH extension. What does it mean?

[image: A screenshot example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the "Extension Pack" counter.

Extension packs can be viewed/filtered here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Extension%20Packs&sortBy=Installs

Where you see the number 1 this appears to be an extension pack with one extension. Perhaps the author of the extension pack intends to add other extensions to the pack in the future?

Here is an example containing 12 related extensions:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials&WT.mc_id=javascript-0000-jopapa